# Como concatenar uma variável mais uma mensagem no "insert"?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-insert, mysql

Tem como concatenar uma variável e uma mensagem no `insert`? Exemplo:

```
declare a int;
set a = 2;
insert into tb_usuario values ('a' + 'fez tal coisa');
```

Comment: Neste caso você está concatenado o caractere 'a' e não a variável a. Tente CONCAT(a, ' fez tal coisa').

Comment: deu certo. obrigada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim, tem, você precisa usar uma função para isto, no caso é a [`CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat). Então ficaria algo assim:

```
insert into tb_usuario values (concat('a', 'fez tal coisa'));
```

Embora esse caso não faz muito sentido fazer assim, espero que esteja usando um campo ou variável aí. Quem sabe queira fazer isto:

```
insert into tb_usuario values (concat(a, 'fez tal coisa'));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Insert/UsingVariable.sql).

Isto inserirá `2fez alguma coisa`.